# magento 2 Product description tab image problem gets smaller?

Tags: magento2, products, image-resizing

[image]

As shown in the image bellow im importing image in product discription with original size is (826px x 8191px) but after importing it it's getting smaller and resized to (152px x 1507px).

how can i keep the image in a big size ?

Comment: i think you css issues. Other css effect your description tab

Comment: no not i checked css its not css issues. when i inspect the image in the browser i found that image original size is changed to a smaller size (152px x 1507px).  (the image not the css ) which mean its resied to a very smaller size